# How to write all the items of a separate lists to a single file

Tags: python, list, file, io

i have made two lists from a database. one list for emails and another for passwords. i am trying to write the lists to a file using. using the following code but only the last items of the lists are getting written to the file

```
from app import db
from app import Users


filtered_users = []
all_users = Users.query.all()
filtered_users = all_users.copy()
# print(filtered_users)
for user in filtered_users:
    `filtered_emails = []`
    `filtered_passwords = []`
    `filtered_emails.append(user.email)`
    `filtered_passwords.append(user.password)`
    `# print(filtered_emails, filtered_passwords)`

with open("users.txt", "w") as f:
    `for email in filtered_emails:`
        `for password in filtered_passwords:`
            `#print(email, password)`
            `print(email, password, file=f)`
```

Comment: how do you need the output file? email,passwords or all emails then all passwords?

Comment: i need the output to be email and the corresponding password on the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop resets `filtered_emails` and `filtered_passwords` on each iteration. You should at least remove that. And at write time you use nested loops (each email against each password) while emails and passwords should be bound.

You should do:

```
filtered_users = []
all_users = Users.query.all()
filtered_users = all_users.copy()
# print(filtered_users)
for user in filtered_users:
    filtered_emails.append(user.email)
    filtered_passwords.append(user.password)
    # print(filtered_emails, filtered_passwords)

with open("users.txt", "w") as f:
    for i, email in enumerate(filtered_emails):
        #print(email, password)
        print(email, filtered_passwords[i], file=f)
```

But it would be simpler to write to the file directly:

```
filtered_users = []
all_users = Users.query.all()
filtered_users = all_users.copy()
# print(filtered_users)
with open("users.txt", "w") as f:
    for user in filtered_users:
        print(user.email, user.password, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try use 'a' instead of 'w',because of the way of 'w' will delete all information and write from the first line。

Comment: using 'a' it is appending the last items of the lists several times to the file thereby coming up with a file of the same entries repeated

Answer (score 0):

```
filtered_emails = ['xx@xx.com','yyy@yy.com','zzz@zz.com']
filtered_passwords = ['1','2','345']
with open("users.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in zip(filtered_emails,filtered_passwords):
        f.write(item[0]+' ')
        f.write(item[1]+'\n')
```

Assuming all of the entries are strings.`zip` returs a `tuple` of username and passwords.you can use `itertools.izip_longest` if you want to deal with lists of unequal length

Output:

```
xx@xx.com 1
yyy@yy.com 2
zzz@zz.com 345
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is still only writing the last items on lists to the file

Comment: post your `email` list to see what you've got?

Comment: when i run `print(filtered_emails, filtered_passwords)` this is the output.  ```['user1@gmail.com'] ['password1']
['user2@gmail.com'] ['password2']
['user3@gmail.com'] ['password3']
['user4@gmail.com'] ['password4']
['user5@gmail.com'] ['password5']```

Comment: `filtered_emails` just print this